# jsPDF: A constructor name should not start with a lowercase letter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, jspdf

I'm trying to create a pdf in React

```
consy myComponent = () => {
   const pdfGenerator = () => {
      const doc = new jsPDF(); //I also tried: new jsPDF('landscape', 'px', 'a4', 'false');
      doc.text('Hello world',10,10)
      doc.save('name.pdf');
   }

  return (
     <button onClick={pdfGenerator} type='button'>Download</button>
  )

}

export default myComponent;
```

But I get **A constructor name should not start with a lowercase letter**.
Even it's exactly like the example from official documentation.
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf]
What is wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: What tool or linter are you using?

Comment: Hi, linter:  ESLint

Comment: Also on facing the same problem

Comment: I solved it, see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From anyone who need it in the future:
I've changed

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
const doc = new jsPDF();
```

to:

```
import JsPDF from 'jspdf';
const doc = new JsPDF();
```

and everything works fine